# Encryption/Decryption For solr

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, solr, solrcloud

I have a solr Cloud cluster, running on different machines, now the data which is indexed needs to be encrypted in such a way that it it stored in the encrypted format on the hard disk and when solr requires the for some queries or to be indexed it should be able to decrypt it do the operation and the data after operation is done should be stored in the encrypted form. I am ok in using amazon s3 if it solves the problem. I have searched and researched a lot but there is no relevant articles,  if someone can give me nudge on some direction or how can i accomplish this it will be really great help.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? Since Solr needs to actually _search_ your index for each query (and thus, have it i clear text) - and if you have access to the file system hosting the index, you can usually extract the key as well. There are usually better ways of implementing encryption for data at rest.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh, the thing is all i need is encryption/decryption layer to be present between solr and and the physical machine, I am new to cryptography so i have no clue how to achieve it. So if you can elaborate on it as in how i can use key with solr to encrypt and decrypt data or something like that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for encrypting indexes, but there are a few open issues with possible patches.

The most promising one is probably [LUCENE-6966](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6966). If you want to implement it yourself, looking at writing a custom codec is probably the way to go.

If you don't want to deal with manual patching or writing code yourself, [Hitachi has a ready-to-deploy solution for Solr and Lucene named Credeon](https://psg.hitachi-solutions.com/credeon/secure-full-text-search).

> To prevent the risk of a data breach from the search indices, Credeon SFS delivers searchable encryption technology which allows the search process to be carried out directly on encrypted data. Specifically, Credeon:
>
> - Encrypts the search indices
> - Uses a unique randomization process for encrypting each plaintext index
> - Searches through encrypted indices in real time
> - Returns search results without decrypting the indices